# Is there a way to replace the Operating System Version in the Get-ADComputer command?

Tags: powershell

This is my first question on stackoverflow and I am fairly new to PowerShell.

I had a question: Would it be possible to replace the Operating System Version number that the command `Get-ADComputer` gives you?

For example, the `Get-ADComputer` command gives you the following output for Operating System Version: 10.0 (18363). I would like to replace that portion of the results to say the version (20H2, 2004, etc.) instead of the build number.

I have the following code:

```
$List = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "dc=DOMAIN,dc=LOCAL" -Filter {operatingsystem -notlike "*server*" -and operatingsystem -notlike "*LTSC*" -and enabled -eq "true"}`
-Properties Name,Description,Operatingsystem,OperatingSystemVersion,IPv4Address |
Sort-Object -Property Name |
Select-Object -Property Name,Description,Operatingsystem,OperatingSystemVersion,IPv4Address
    foreach($System in $List){        
        Switch -Wildcard ($System.OperatingSystemVersion){
            '*10240*'{"$($System.Name) -- $($System.Description)`n$($System.Operatingsystem)`t`t1507`t`t$($System.IPv4Address)`n"}
            '*10586*'{"$($System.Name) -- $($System.Description)`n$($System.Operatingsystem)`t`t1511`t`t$($System.IPv4Address)`n"}
            '*14393*'{"$($System.Name) -- $($System.Description)`n$($System.Operatingsystem)`t`t1607`t`t$($System.IPv4Address)`n"}
            '*15063*'{"$($System.Name) -- $($System.Description)`n$($System.Operatingsystem)`t`t1703`t`t$($System.IPv4Address)`n"}
            '*16299*'{"$($System.Name) -- $($System.Description)`n$($System.Operatingsystem)`t`t1709`t`t$($System.IPv4Address)`n"}
            '*17134*'{"$($System.Name) -- $($System.Description)`n$($System.Operatingsystem)`t`t1803`t`t$($System.IPv4Address)`n"}
            '*17763*'{"$($System.Name) -- $($System.Description)`n$($System.Operatingsystem)`t`t1809`t`t$($System.IPv4Address)`n"}
            '*18362*'{"$($System.Name) -- $($System.Description)`n$($System.Operatingsystem)`t`t1903`t`t$($System.IPv4Address)`n"}
            '*18363*'{"$($System.Name) -- $($System.Description)`n$($System.Operatingsystem)`t`t1909`t`t$($System.IPv4Address)`n"}
            '*19041*'{"$($System.Name) -- $($System.Description)`n$($System.Operatingsystem)`t`t2004`t`t$($System.IPv4Address)`n"}
            '*19042*'{"$($System.Name) -- $($System.Description)`n$($System.Operatingsystem)`t`t20H2`t`t$($System.IPv4Address)`n"}
            Default {"$($System.Name) -- $($System.Description)`n$($System.Operatingsystem)`t`t$($System.OperatingSystemVersion)`t`t$($System.IPv4Address)`n"}
        }
    }
```

I wasn't able to replace the the Operating System Number directly from the `$List` I created, so I ended up using a `-Wildcard` `Switch` to, essentially, replace the whole table that was created.

I have two problems with this code:

1. It does not output the information is the most pleasing format.
2. I have yet to find a way to output this `Switch` to a file or other format.

If you guys have any ideas on what I might be missing or doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what does the output return?

Comment: You can certainly do string manipulation on returned data from AD. If you want to change the property value in AD, then `Set-ADComputer -OperatingSystemVersion` seems to be a thing.

Answer (score 0):

What does this do for you?

```
$List = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "dc=DOMAIN,dc=LOCAL" -Filter {operatingsystem -notlike "*server*" -and operatingsystem -notlike "*LTSC*" -and enabled -eq "true"}`
-Properties Name,Description,Operatingsystem,OperatingSystemVersion,IPv4Address |
Sort-Object -Property Name |
Select-Object -Property Name,Description,Operatingsystem,OperatingSystemVersion,IPv4Address
    foreach($System in $List){        
        $OS = Switch -Wildcard ($System.OperatingSystemVersion){
            '*10240*'{"1507"}
            '*10586*'{"1511"}
            '*14393*'{"1607"}
            '*15063*'{"1703"}
            '*16299*'{"1709"}
            '*17134*'{"1803"}
            '*17763*'{"1809"}
            '*18362*'{"1903"}
            '*18363*'{"1909"}
            '*19041*'{"2004"}
            '*19042*'{"20H2"}
            Default {"$_"}
        }
    }


        [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $($System.Name)
        OSVersion    = $OS
        ComputerDescription = $($System.Description)
        IPAddress = $($System.IPv4Address)
    } | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more digging and research, I found the following code to be working for me:

```
$ADComputerProperties = @{
SearchBase = "dc=ad,dc=dersys,dc=com" 
Filter     = { operatingsystem -notlike "*server*" -and operatingsystem -notlike "*LTSC*" -and enabled -eq "true" }
Properties = 'Name', 'Description', 'Operatingsystem', 'OperatingSystemVersion', 'IPv4Address'
}

$list = Get-ADComputer @ADComputerProperties

$data = 
foreach ($System in $List) {       
Switch -Wildcard ($System.OperatingSystemVersion) {
    '*10240*' {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            SystemName      = $System.name
            Description     = $System.Description
            Operatingsystem = $System.Operatingsystem
            Version         = '1507'
            IPv4Address     = $System.IPv4Address
        }
    }
    '*10586*' {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            SystemName      = $System.name
            Description     = $System.Description
            Operatingsystem = $System.Operatingsystem
            Version         = '1511'
            IPv4Address     = $System.IPv4Address
        }
    }
    '*14393*' {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            SystemName      = $System.name
            Description     = $System.Description
            Operatingsystem = $System.Operatingsystem
            Version         = '1607'
            IPv4Address     = $System.IPv4Address
        }
    }
    '*15063*' {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            SystemName      = $System.name
            Description     = $System.Description
            Operatingsystem = $System.Operatingsystem
            Version         = '1703'
            IPv4Address     = $System.IPv4Address
        }
    }
    '*16299*' {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            SystemName      = $System.name
            Description     = $System.Description
            Operatingsystem = $System.Operatingsystem
            Version         = '1709'
            IPv4Address     = $System.IPv4Address
        }
    }
    #etc
    Default {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            SystemName      = $System.name
            Description     = $System.Description
            Operatingsystem = $System.Operatingsystem
            Version         = '-'
            IPv4Address     = $System.IPv4Address
        }
    }
}
}

$data
$data | export-csv ".\export.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Thanks!